# Yesterday from the beatles structure and form. 8 bar verse or 7 bar verse

Tags: theory

It is common to say that yesterday from the beatles is the perfect song, and the perfect song has 8 measures bars, why do people says it is a 8 bar verse and i count 2 measures of intro and 7 measure for the first verse instead of 8 measures.

Comment: Who says it's the perfect song? There must be thousands of more 'perfect' songs out there.

Answer (score 1):

"Yesterday", as recorded on the album *Help*, has the form:

- Intro: 2 bars
- Verse 1: 7 bars
- Verse 2: 7 bars
- Chorus: 8 bars
- Verse 3: 7 bars
- Chorus: 8 bars
- Verse 3: 7 bars
- Outro: 2 bars

Being a "perfect song" has little to do with the specific number of measures involved and a lot to do with all of the other musical aspects: melody, harmony, rhythm, and how those three fit together, lyrics, and how the lyrics  are complemented by the melody, harmony, and rhythm, instrumentation, the quality of the performers, the recording quality, etc., etc., etc.

In a Classical view toward art, "balance" is an essential value, and in music — particularly the era known as the Classical era — numerical balance was considered a key element. Music is often found in 8-measure phrases, or at least in multiples of two. Not all music, but a vast quantity of it.

However, a more Romantic approach to art focuses more on the emotions and less on the more formal aspects of structure.

So, how one evaluates "Yesterday" might depend on whether one looks at it from a Classical or Romantic aesthetic, and how rigidly one defines that aesthetic.

Here's another "perfect" song, "Erlkönig", by Franz Schubert. It has an intro of 15 measures, which "should be" 16 by the standard set in the question, but that doesn't impact the song's aesthetic value. The verse is even worse, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

"Measures" and "bars" are the same thing, and 8 of them is not perfect.

I answered another question about phrase length in https://music.stackexchange.com/a/81448/23919, and pointed out how 2, 3, and 4 bar phrase - or phrase segement, depending on how you define terms - lengths are very common. Also, single measure ideas can be used like prefixes, suffixes, or links.

If you look at the odd 7 bar verses of the Beatles song *Yesterday*, you should note that the segments are more like `1+2+2+2` so that we have a little 1 bar prefix added to very ordinary 2 bar length segments.

Importantly the duration of that initial 1 bar idea *matches the length of the single word "yesterday."* 1 bar duration is all you need to sing "yesterday." Basic songcraft could have extended that phrase to 2 bars by using half notes, or repeating the word. But doing so would only serve to tailor the music to 8 bar section lengths. The choice to go with only 7 bars decides to set the music in service to the lyrics with phrase lengths that naturally fit the text.

There is a use of the word "perfect" in music theory which I think should be addressed here. Harmonic intervals can be described as "perfect" and "imperfect". I also have a basic awareness that [Medieval music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_music#Rhythm) used "perfect" and "imperfect" to describe rhythm, and that was related to divisions of three versus divisions of two, which is a very tenuous connection to the topic of 8 bar, or even numbers of bars, phrase lengths. That use of "perfect" and "imperfect" is just a way to categorize certain musical elements. It doesn't mean perfect in the sense of "without flaw".

Along those lines you *might* call even number of bars phrase lengths as "perfect" and odd lengths as "imperfect", but I've not read any such music theory. Even if someone had that meaning in mind, it wouldn't mean songs with odd length phrasing are imperfect, flawed songs.

Comment: 'Naturally fit the text' - *Scrambled eggs*....

Comment: I love that story... but seriously, same number of syllables, same accent placement.

Comment: @JOrdan "8 [bars] is not perfect": to elaborate, there's a chance or a sense in which this seven-bar phrasing is part of what makes it such a great song. In the simplest, it creates aesthetic interest by disrupting our expectation. You could get deeper—deeper, certainly, than McCartney consciously intended, but maybe true on unconscious levels: You could say, like Kintsugi pottery, it "breaks" a rule, but then makes this "brokenness" a highlight; like "Heidegger's [broken] hammer," it makes us (subconsciously) aware of phrase length in a way we aren't normally.